# How often do municipal bond ratings change per year?

Tags: municipal-bonds

I'm working with a financial planner. For various reasons I won't go into, l would like to buy individual muni bonds. For several reasons my planner is suggesting I let his company manage my individual muni bonds. One reason they suggest managing my individual muni bonds is that they can watch for rating changes until the bond matures. My practical question is, how often do municipal bond ratings in the United States change per year?

I searched the internet and can't find a specific answer. I was only able to find an article in The Journal of Finance from 1983 titled "The Information Content of Municipal Bond Rating Changes: A Note". The data they used was rather old from May 1977 to April 1978.

In addition, I would have to pay for a membership to access Standards and Poor's or Moody's just to answer the question above.

Any answers to this post, please cite your source so that I can read it first hand.

Thanks.

Comment: Ask whoever writes the ratings that you are using?

Comment: The rules, if any, depend on jurisdiction. What country are you investing in?

Answer (score -1):

I found it.

I searched S&P, Moody's and Fitch. Only Fitch had this info publicly available (thanks Fitch!)

Go to
https://www.fitchratings.com/topics/ratings-snapshot
Scroll down to the first horizontal bar chart.
Choose the "USPF" tab for "US Public Finance".
On the Y axis there are several entities that are related to munis (state obligations, water & sewer, etc.)
Currently, it shows "Percentage of Sector by Change in Rating or Outlook/Watch  since Mar 1, 2020".

To  answer the question "How often do municipal bond ratings change per year?" - it depends.

It depends on the type of municipal bond that was issued. Per the site linked above, between March 1, 2020 and June 3, 2022 there were 582 "City Obligations" muni bonds ratings. During that time there were 93 rating changes made to that type of muni bond (it was downgraded 33 times, placed on "Outlook/Watch negative" 20 times, "Outlook Watch positive" 16 times and upgraded 24 times). For this type of muni bond there have been 41.3 rating changes per year (93 rating changes / 2.25 years).

Please see the Fitch site linked above for the number of rating changes on 12 other types of muni bonds. I provided as much information as I can to answer the original question without violating copyright. I also cited my source. If this is still insufficient I'll ask the moderator to delete this question since the answer is more complex than I previously thought. I apologize. With experience you learn. Can we please stop the down votes?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is: how often do municipal bond ratings change per year? Is it once per year? Twice per year?

Comment: It does answer the question: "It depends. Here's where I found some of the information if you want reasonably current details on specific bonds".